# Connectivity Problem

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms, approximation-algorithms, approximation-hardness

Hi. I have a problem but not sure if there is some literature on it or whether it has a standard name. Please let me know some reference from where I can begin.

Given undirected graph along with some pairs of nodes $s_i$ and $t_i$, we want to connect as many pairs in the graph as possible such that paths are edge disjoint.

Please comment on approximation and hardness results if any.

Comment: I guess you are referring to the [Maximum Disjoint Connecting Paths](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node122.html) problem; see the link for references.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maximize Edge Disjoint Paths (EDP)

The problem is NP Hard and here are some results:

1) It accepts $O(\sqrt{m})$ approximation by Kleinberg in 96 in general graphs.

2) The above is tight for directed graphs (Guruswami et. al.).

3) Inapproximation result by Andrews, Zhang : O($log ^{\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon}n$).

4) For planar graphs, Chekuri et. al. has found a O(1) approx with any edge being in O(1) paths.

I will update with references later but you can google out.

EDIT: There is a recent paper by Chekuri in 06 which has improvised it to $O(\sqrt(n))$ in undirected graphs. You will get the above references in that paper. The paper is at

theoryofcomputing.org/articles/v002a007/v002a007.ps.gz